# Formatting dynamic timestamps

Tags: php, regex

I have a dynamic var coming from json with the following in PHP

```
$timestamp = $array['timestamp'];
```

The timestamp shows as:

```
2018-09-22T05:28:45.676899Z
```

But i want it to show as:

```
2018-09-22 - 05:28:45
```

I have no idea how i would go about doing this, The timestamp is dynamic and changes every minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your timestamp into a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and then you can print it out in any form you like using the [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method. In your particular case:

```
$timestamp = '2018-09-22T05:28:45.676899Z';
$date = new DateTime($timestamp);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d - H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2018-09-22 - 05:28:45
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, using `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "2018-09-22T05:28:45.676899Z";
$output = preg_replace("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[T\s]?(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/", "$1 - $2", $input);
echo $input ."\n" . $output;

2018-09-22T05:28:45.676899Z
2018-09-22 - 05:28:45
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("Y-m-d - H:i:s", strtotime("2018-09-22T05:28:45.676899Z"));
```

output

```
2018-09-21 - 22:28:45
```